# IndexError while getting the sum of the anti diagonal of my matrix (list of lists)

Tags: python, python-3.x, index-error

I am trying to get the sum of the anti diagonal of a matrix. Using my code

```
r=int(input("Enter no of rows:"))
c=int(input("Enter no of cols:"))
a=[]
for i in range(r):
    a.append([0]*c)
print("Enter elements:")
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[0])):
        a[i][j]=int(input())
for  i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[0])):
        print(a[i][j],end=" ")
    print()
n=0    
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a),0,-1):
        z=a[i][j]+n
print(z)
```

I got error in finding the sum of anti diagonal of matrix of list index out of range i.e of index error:

```
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    z=a[i][j]+n
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: for j the last index is `len(a) -1` and not `len(a)`

Answer (score 1):

You have several bugs in your code:

- you use the range command wrongly, the first index is *inclusive*, the last index *exclusive* - when going backwards you need `(len-1,-1,-1)` not `(len,0,-1)`
- you sum up wrongly, you sum ALL values, not only the diagonal
- you sum up wrongly, overwriting `z` every time without increasing `n`

See inline comments for errors / fixes / improvements.

I replaced the manual inputs with fixed values / random values to cut short on manual input:

```
import random

r = 5
c = 5
a = []  

# add random numbers into list of list    
for i in range(r):
    a.append([])
    for j in range(c):
        a[-1].append(random.randint(1,500))

# print data formatted
# do not recalc len(a) / len(a[0]) all the time, use r and c
for  i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        print("{:>5}".format(a[i][j]),end=" ")
    print()

# sum anti diagonal
n=0    

# this calculates the sum of _all_ values, not of the diagonal 
# do not recalc len(a) / len(a[0]) all the time, use r and c 
for i in range(r):
    # for j in range(c,0,-1):  
    # range uses (inclusive,exclusive,step) limits - your c is 1 too high
    # because of 0-indexing. fix using 
    for j in range(c-1,-1,-1):
        # z=a[i][j]+n
        # you need to increment n - not do stuff to z
        n += a[i][j]
print(n)
```

Output:

```
   33    69   430   218    15 
  149   327    44    33   279 
  327    57   431    57   195 
  307   460   268   465   170 
  154   325   380    79   217 

5489  # sum of ALL values
```

To get only the diagonal you need to sum only 5 values, you loop over 5*5 values.

---

You can get the correct indexes using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) of two [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)s:

```
# generating just the indexes you need
idx = list(zip(range(r),range(c-1,-1,-1)))  
print(idx)  #  [(0, 4), (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 0)]
```

and sum up these indexes.

You can loop over these tuples - or use pythons built in [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function.

You can either use ranges counting up/down *or* ranges counting up and *negative list indexing* (equivalent):

```
# using a range counting down for columns
print(sum( a[row][col] for row,col in zip(range(r), range(c-1,-1,-1)) ))

# using negative list indexing and a range counting upwards
print(sum( a[row][-col-1] for row,col in zip(range(r), range(c)) ))
```

Output:

```
1093 # twice
```

---

To fill `a` you could also use a list comprehension:

```
a = [ [random.randint(1,500) for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)]   # automatic or
a = [ [int(input("Number: ")) for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)   # manual input
```

---

Doku:

- [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)
- [sum()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)
- [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)